# Best approach creating indefinite loop android

Tags: android, loops, for-loop, android-asynctask, while-loop

i was wondering what is best approach in creating indefinite loop in android programming keeping in mind performance? (something like for(;;), AsyncTask or while(true)...). Cheers.

Comment: This entirely depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Can you provide more details?

Comment: For example, manipulating phones hardware LEDs etc..

Comment: Beside that I would like to know in general, what is best approach in most common use cases.Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use indefinite `while` or `for` loop it decreases the performance of the app considerably, freezes the UI and after some time you will get `application not responding` error if you do your task in UI thread itself.

Instead if you want to do some task continuously with some time interval, consider the use of `Timer`.

```
TimerTask timer= new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Do your task here

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //Task which involves manipulating UI
                }
            });
        }
```

Then you can call `Timer` at a fixed rate.

```
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer , 0 , 5000);
```

So the above code calls the `TimerTask` for each `5 seconds(5000 ms)`. Since it runs on the separate thread there will be no issue regarding performance.

For more info you can refer the official doc, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html